# How to extract few fields from the response of Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

How to extract few fields from the response of Elasticsearch. I tried following ways:

1) `"_source": ["f1", "f2"]`
2) `"fields" : ["f1", "f2"]`
3) `"_source": { "include" : ["f1", "f2"] }`

All the above queries responded all the fields(40). Kindly help.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Please show the complete query and how you're sending it (i.e. which which client, curl, Sense, etc)

Comment: I got the resolution. Actually, we need to query something, then only _source will return any response.

Comment: Thanks for your concern.